# PHP Regex: split a string on numeric value

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a code that can receive 2 types of string:

1. text number text

   ```
   danny levitt 48 new york
   ```
2. text number [comma] text

   ```
   danny levitt 48, new york
   ```

The text on both size can be a single word or more, and the language might not be english.

I need those strings to return to me in an array as follows:

```
    Array (
        0 => "danny levitt",
        1 => "48",
        2 => "new york"
    )
```

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/8MT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your input according to the space which exists just before to the number and the space which follows the same number. `\K` discards the previously matched characters.

```
$string = "danny levitt 48, new york";
$regex = '~\s+(?=\b\d+,?)|\b\d+\K,?\s+~';
$splits = preg_split($regex, $string);
print_r($splits);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => danny levitt
    [1] => 48
    [2] => new york
)
```